# Getting error when loading CSV file to dataframe using Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, csv, pyspark, jupyter

```
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
sqlCxt = SQLContext(sc)
df=sqlCxt.read.format("csv").option("delimiter","|").load("D:/SparkPy/u.item")
```

Error:

> ERROR:root:An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input
>   The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
>   The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line string', (651, 72))

Comment: This error is not related to pyspark. Your file is missing a quote ,apostrophe or something else. check the line number  given in error message.

Comment: This does'nt look like csv issue,even after creating a dummy csv and using it,I am getting  the same error.

Comment: can you share the content of minimum possible dummy csv file which generates the above error?

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved when I updated the Spark to version 2.2.0 .

Python 3.6 is compatible with Spark v2.2.0