# Loading file into Jupiter Notebook

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Recently followed a short Python bootcamp and have been trying to work on it myself a bit more, but get stuck at the start. We need to upload the data, but for some reason I can't get it to work. In the example it was done like this:

[Correct way apparently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqaCq.png)

So I figured it was just about the file path, so tried to copy that but don't get it to work

[My wrong attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXE3s.png)

Any help would be thoroughly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try saving the notebook in the same directory where the CSV file exists and use a relative path to import the CSV?

```
data/titatic.csv
```

or

```
titatic.csv
```

Comment: Also check out this link if it is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46454590/getting-error-when-loading-csv-file-to-dataframe-using-jupyter-notebook

Comment: Then it indicates 'titanic'/'data' is not defined